# SpriteKit game behaves incorrectly when compiled for arm64

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arm64

I have an old SpriteKit game that I'm trying to revive. I've tried the game on my iPhone 6 Plus and the objects were acting incorrectly (positions messing up, making game unplayable). I've first thought it was due to screen size, then I've tried different iOS versions, knowing that SpriteKit is buggy on iOS 9. I couldn't pinpoint the problem until I've tried exact same OS on iPhone 5 and 5s. On 5, my game was behaving correctly, but on 5s, it was behaving incorrectly. I've removed `arm64` from build targets, forcing it to compile and run on 32-bit mode on iPhone 5s too, and it was working perfectly again.

I've checked my code to find any piece that relied on bitness of the architecture (e.g. something relying on floats being 32-bit etc), but couldn't find anything suspicious. I know it's hard for anyone to tell anything exact without seeing the code, but it's also impossible for me to post the code of the whole game.

Is there anything well-known that I would be missing that would affect the game's behavior on `arm64`?

**UPDATE:** I've changed all my `float`s to `CGFloat`s, but no avail. There are no `double`s in my code.

Comment: `float` should always be 32-bit and `double` should always be 64-bit, because IEEE 754. It's the size of _integer_ types you need to worry about.

Comment: @Notlikethat yeah but `CGFloat` is 32bit on arm and 64bit on arm64 AFAIK as in `CGBase.h`: `#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

/* Definition of the `CGFloat' type and `CGFLOAT_DEFINED'. */

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
#define CGFLOAT_DEFINED 1`

I'm still not getting it, if was the other way around, I'd think of overflows etc, but it's not.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Can you at least isolate the part of the code which can reproduce what you are saying (or at least shows some oddities / inconsistencies) , and update your question with that code ? Also,  note that comments are not suitable for pasting the code in it (because of readability). It would be better to update your question instead with additional data.

Comment: @Whirlwind believe me, I would if I could. But I have no idea where the problem arises from, and there are many classes and it could be something at any single line of them. If I could ever create a SSCCE for this issue, I would have already posted it. (btw that code really belonged to the comment as it's just an answer to another comment, but I agree with readability part.)